# check old ldap password if it is expired

Tags: exception, ldap

I am facing some problem.

In LDAP for admin I set the maximum password age pwdMaxAge to 6 mins for testing. When the user tried to login after 6 mins(after the password expire time), I am showing to re-set the password.Then user enters old passowrd with new password. I am validating if the user enters correct old password using below code.

```
ldapConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.LDAP_V3, getDN(jurNm, username),
                new String(oldPassword).getBytes(),constraints)
```

but it is throwing exceptions.

"LDAPException: Invalid Credentials (49) Invalid Credentials
LDAPException: Matched DN: "

could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the password policy overlay. To change an expired password you need to use the extended password-change operation, where you supply the old password and the new one, and you have to do it as an admin user whose password has not expired.

Also, to get password-expiry warnings, grace period notifications, etc, you need to use the password policy request control, and examine the response controls that are sent with a successful bind or an exception.

Comment: Here the admin user whose password is expired and when he tries to login using old password then I am showing re-set password page.

So you are saying if the admin user password expired, the same admin user can not re-set his password?

Comment: The admin user probably shouldn't have an expiring password at all. You should certainly not be *testing* with the admin user, but with an ordinary user. In the case of an admin user you may need to execute the code as the rootDN.

Comment: We have to admin group 

1. Super Admin

2. Admin,

for super admin we don't have password max age but, for admin we have max password age. And for the admin whose password expired can re-set the password if it expired.

Comment: my question is, how to check if the entered old expired password  is exist in ldap or not using the above novel.ldap?

Comment: And, for the third time, I've answered it. Extended password-change operation and password policy request control.